# java program not running by its name

Tags: java, linux

I am running simple java program using on redhat 6.2
I am starting the program using the following command

```
java -cp "$CLASSPATH:/home/vikas/Myjar.jar" com.vikas.MyProgram <args>
```

The program has an infinite while loop and should always be running.
However the problem is when i do the following on another terminal on same machine

```
ps -ef| grep -i MyProgram
```

This does not produce any result. However, I can see my program is running fine.

However, if I execute

```
ps -ef|grep -i java
```

This fetches multiple results including one running as my user "vikas"

Is there a way i can force the program to run by its own name?

Comment: Does it work properly if you create a script that starts the Java application?

Comment: Technically you're not running your program, you're running `java` (i.e. `java -cp`).

Comment: You could do as @apemanzilla suggests and put the `java -cp foo bar <args>` command in a script and name that script `MyProgram`, then `chmod 777 MyProgram`, and then execute the script (i.e. `./MyProgram`). The process should then have `MyProgram` as its name.

Comment: Most likely no. But to list java processes you can use [jps](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/share/jps.html)

Comment: If you're launching the program as you describe, then although its *name* does not include the string "MyProgram", its *arguments* do, and the `-f` flag ought to be causing those to be included in the process list for `grep` to see.  Something is not adding up here.  Can you provide an [mcve]?